# how do I add “contact page or custom link” at top menu bar in OpenCart?

Tags: menu, version, opencart

how do I add “contact page or custom link”  at top menu bar in OpenCart?

i am using Version 2.1.0.2

how can i add "homepage and other page" at responsive menu in opencart?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally add it to the header.tpl file which is in `catalog/view/theme/{name of theme}/template/common/header.tpl`
and look for the `li` item that corresponds to where you want to add the menu and add it in by adding a new line with the code
 `<li><a href="{link}">{Name of Menu Item}</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl

Add Following line before ul close, it may around line number 115.

```
<li><a href="index.php?route=information/contact">Contact Us</a><li>
```

Answer (score 0):

On my opencart v2.3.0.2,

I just need to add new Links (contact page) at OC CMS Block (index.php?route=extension/module/occmsblock/cmslist&token=) then choose type as Link, fill links column to "index.php?route=information/contact", then after it created, just edit horizontal megamenu (in my theme) and add those new link (contact page) and it will be displayed at header.